# How to Find text present in List tag using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

```html
<li class="top-offset-micro">
                        Order date: <strong>12/18/2016</strong>
                    </li>
<li class="top-offset-micro">
                        <strong>Estimated delivery:</strong> 12/27&nbsp;―&nbsp;1/3
                    </li>
```

Here I need to find  only `12/27 - 1/3` using `Selenium` `C#`.
I have tried

```
var EDD_OnConfirm = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//strong[contains(text(),'')]")); 
return EDD_OnConfirm.Text;
```

Which returned `Estimated Delivery not 12/27 - 1/3`
And also tried with

```
 var EDD_OnConfirm = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(" //*[@id='confirmation']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/text()"));")); 
 return EDD_OnConfirm.Text;
```

Where `text()` element is not supported in `selenium`

Comment: Do you have to do it on retrieval? Why not retrieve the entire text, and then remove unneeded text using normal string manipulation?

Comment: yes did the same thing after retrieval trim the text

Comment: My code goes like this                                                                        public string EDD_ConfirmationPage()
        {_transactionalPageSyncObject.WaitForPageLoad("/confirmation");  _EDD = TransactionalPages.ConfirmationPage.GetEDD();
 Console.WriteLine("EDD:" + _EDD); return _EDD;
        }

Comment: public string GetEDD()
        {
            _transactionalPageSync.WaitForPageLoad(Url);
            Console.WriteLine("Getting the EDD from the Thank you page");
            string temp = EDD_Confirmation.Text.Trim().Split(':')[1];
            Console.WriteLine("EDD={0}", temp);
            return temp.Trim();
          }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the html markup is poor on the estimated delivery. The date should be in a span tag.

```
var edd = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[2]")).Text;
```

This returns some poor text due to the html spaces: Estimated delivery: 12/27 â€• 1/3

Then like Kiril said you could remove the "Esitimated Delivery" by using a simple string replacement to get the date.